# Find out the angle of <ABC

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, triangles

Help me to solve it please.how could it be done.I tried but nothing comes out.Help me please

[image]

Comment: is trigonometry allowed?

Comment: See $\#132$ of http://www.qbyte.org/puzzles/puzzle14.html

Comment: Drop a perpendicular from $A$ to $CB$ and notice characteristic 90-45-45 (half of a square)and 90-60-30 (half of equilateral triangle) triangles. Since the angle at $B$ is obviously $>90^\circ$, try dividing it somehow to two angles ($30^\circ+x$, $45^\circ+x$, $90^\circ+x$, etc).

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Let $\angle BAD = \alpha$, so by sine rule,
$$\frac{\sin \alpha}{BD}=\frac{\sin 45^{\circ}}{AB}$$
and 
$$\frac{\sin (\alpha+ 15^{\circ})}{2BD}=\frac{\sin 30^{\circ}}{AB}$$
so
$$\frac{2\sin \alpha}{\sin (\alpha+ 15^{\circ})}=\frac{\sin 45^{\circ}}{\sin 30^{\circ}}$$

After finding $\alpha$, you can then find $\angle ABC$

Answer (score 0):

we draw BO$\perp$AC and we join OD

- see in $\bigtriangleup$BOC $\angle$BOC=90 and OD is midian. so OD=BD=DC
- NOW $\angle$OCD=30 so $\angle$OBD=60=$\angle$NOD[ where BO meets AD at N]
- now $\angle$NBD=60 and $\angle$NDB=45 so $\angle$BND=75
- $\angle$BND=75 and $\angle$NOD=60 so  $\angle$ODN=15=$\angle$OAD. so AO=OD
- now $\angle$ODB=45+15=60. so $\bigtriangleup$BOD is equilateral. so OD=BO =BD AND AO=OD
- so we have AO=BO and we see $\angle$AOB=90 so $\angle$OAB=45
- we name $\angle$DAB=x so x+15 =45 so x=30
- in $\bigtriangleup$ABD $\angle$DAB=30 and $\angle$ADB=45 so $\angle$ABC=105[image]

Answer (score 0):

Do construction as shown [image: Here.]
WLOG, we can let BD = DC = 1.

Applying special angle relations to $\triangle AHC$, we have 
$h : h + 1 = 1 : \sqrt{3} \leftrightarrow h = \frac{\sqrt(3) +1} {2}$

Then calculate $h - 1$ for later use. $h – 1 = \frac {\sqrt(3) – 1} {2}$

In $\triangle AHB, AB^2 = h^2 + (h – 1)^2 \leftrightarrow AB = \sqrt 2$

Then, $\dfrac {AB}{BD} = \dfrac {\sqrt 2}{1}$ and $\dfrac {BC}{AB} = \dfrac {2}{\sqrt 2} = \dfrac {\sqrt 2}{1}$.

By ratio of 2 sides and the included angle, $\triangle ABC\sim\triangle DBA$.

Therefore, $\angle BAD = \angle BCA = 30^{\circ}$

Hence $\angle ABC = 105^{\circ}$

Note:- This figure is commonly used in calculating sin (15).