# Prove that $45°$ angle can be trisected with straightedge and compass.

Tags: abstract-algebra, geometric-construction

I want to prove that $45°$ angle can be trisected for this i have to show that $\sin 15°$  or $\cos 15°$ is constructible.

How can i show that $\sin 15° \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$?

Comment: http://www.cut-the-knot.org/pythagoras/cos15.shtml

Comment: Do you know how to make a 30 degree angle with a straight edge and compass?  Can you bisect the 30 degree angle?

Answer (score 3):

Use the fact that

$$\sin{(a - b)} = \sin{a} \cos{b} - \cos{a} \sin{b}$$

with $a = 45^{\circ}$ and $b = 30^{\circ}$.

Answer (score 0):

Reference : Check my answer to the question http:// [Find out the angle of <ABC](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/576898/find-out-the-angle-of-abc/577333#577333)

Answer (score 0):

There is a similar problem solved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4609316/715008). What you have to do is to build a $30^\circ$ angle internal to the $45^\circ$, internal and sharing one arm. Then bisect the $30^\circ$ in order to get the $45^\circ$ trisected.