# Prove that 54° angle can be trisected with straightedge and compass

Tags: abstract-algebra

I know how to prove 45° angle can be trisected with a straightedge and compass, but as to 54°, I don't know the cos or sin of this degree, how can I build a solution? Thanks.

Comment: In fact, one has $\sin 18^\circ=(\sqrt{5}-1)/4$. See also https://mathworld.wolfram.com/TrigonometryAnglesPi10.html

Comment: OHHHH, thanks a lot.

Comment: Why "angle trisection" is not Possible? I don't get it. Thanks.

Comment: Despite there are angles which allow trisection that isn't true for all angles.

Comment: Construct three copies such that one is adjacent to the other two and then extend one of the "outer" rays to define the supplement of the sum.

Answer (score 2):

An angle is internal to another larger angle if they share the terminal atm while the initial arm of the smaller angle is internal to the larger one.

Step 1: construct an angle of 45° internal to the 54°

Step 2: double the resulting 9° angle to obtain the first 18° internal to the 54°

Step 3: bisect the remaining 36° angle.